# recursion issue with preventDefault on form submit with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, preventdefault

I have a form that takes some inputs, everything there is peachy.  From this form I want to take a input value and assign it to a hidden value via jquery.  To do this I had written the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        function preventDefault(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        jQuery('#rsvp-form').bind('submit', preventDefault);
        jQuery('#rsvp-form').submit(function(e) {
            var emailvalue = jQuery('#personemail\\[0\\]').val();
            jQuery('#person_email').val(emailvalue);
            alert(jQuery("#person_email").val());
            jQuery('#rsvp-form').unbind('submit', preventDefault);
            jQuery(this).trigger('submit');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm binding .preventDefault to the submit just fine along with changing my value without issue.  The problem is submitting the form after changing the value.  No matter what I've tried it ends in an endless loop.  If I remove the trigger or a .submit() or something along those lines and just leave it with the unbind, nothing happens.  Kind of stumped at this point.

Comment: why do you need the preventDefault in the first place?

Comment: the #person_email field is hidden.  The preventDefault is needed in order to stop the submission so I can assign a value to the hidden field from another input on the form(named personemail[0] in this case), then submit the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need any of that. If you want to set that value before the form submits you can do so easily like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#rsvp-form').submit(function(e) {
        var emailvalue = jQuery('#personemail\\[0\\]').val();
        jQuery('#person_email').val(emailvalue);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the native `submit` method, rather than triggering the jQuery event.

```
jQuery('#rsvp-form').submit(function(e) {
    var emailvalue = jQuery('#personemail\\[0\\]').val();
    jQuery('#person_email').val(emailvalue);
    alert(jQuery("#person_email").val());
    jQuery('#rsvp-form').unbind('submit', preventDefault);
    this.submit(); // <-- this line here
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works perfect, however it would appear hunter was right, I really didn't need to bother with the preventDefault stuff in my situation.  Thanks a lot for the help though, I'll def. remember the distinction between the trigger and using the native method.